# AppInsight java agent add invalid character to Operation Id

Tags: azure-application-insights

There are two micro services A, B. When A calls REST API in B, A uses the header "request-id" to pass down the correlation id. The value of request id is like SA8802b6851efb05. Service A uses application insight java agent to send Telemetry to application insight. Service A doesn't have any custom app insight code. For some reason, Application Insight generates an operation id like "SA8802b6851efb05,|e7cce3c908fa6c9e1a87c3e8967486cf". The additional ",|e6cce3c908fa6c9e1a86c3e8967486cf" is unexpected.

We use applicationinsights-agent 3.0.0.

How can we configure app insight to just use the original value in request-id as operation id? We will prefer to not add custom code and just rely on json configuration if possible.

We don't have any custom code related to app insight. All we do is run our jar file with app insight agent like this.

```
export APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=keyhere
java -javaagent:applicationinsights-agent-3.0.0.jar -jar service.jar.
```

We bundle a config file like below.

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">
  <!-- The key from the portal: -->

  <!--InstrumentationKey>key should be passed as env variable APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_IKEY</InstrumentationKey-->


  <!-- HTTP request component (not required for bare API) -->

  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
  </TelemetryModules>

  <!-- Events correlation (not required for bare API) -->
  <!-- These initializers add context data to each event -->

  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSyntheticRequestTelemetryInitializer"/>
  </TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Comment: From my searching result, it seems impossible to set custom operation id without adding custom code. Could you pls share you code or setting to demonstrate how you make the operation id have the value like `SA8802b6851efb05,|e7cce3c9....` ?

Comment: @QAQ please see my updated question with the setting and how we run the service.

Comment: Odd here, when using java application insights, we don't need to do any configurations any more. Than config file seems needless but it's weird that you got the special operation id without any code.